# Grails nested taglibs that use templates?

Tags: grails, taglib

I want to create taglibs to simplify a webpage that represents a user dashboard.  There are 2 taglibs I want to create.  The first is a generic panel that will be used elsewhere, the second is a more specific version of the panel.

The GSP is called from a controller with the following model:

```
def index() {
    def timelineItems = [
        [details: "Some text"],
        [details: "Some other text"]
    ]

    render(view: "index", model: [timelineItems: timelineItems])
}
```

My desired GSP looks like this:

```
<dash:panel panelClass="col-lg-8" panelTitle="Service History">
    <p>Some text in the body here</p>
    <dash:timelinePanel timelineItems="$timelineItems" />
</dash:panel>
```

I want to put my HTML code in templates to make editing it simpler, so I call render from inside the tag lib and pass a data model.  The taglibs look like this (within a namespace called dash):

```
def panel = {attrs, body ->
        out << render(template: "/dashboard/dashboardPanel", model:[panelClass: attrs.getAt("panelClass"), panelTitle: attrs.getAt("panelTitle"), body: body()])
    }

def timelinePanel = { attrs ->
        out << render(template: "/dashboard/dashboardTimelinePanel", model: [timelineItems: attrs.getAt("timelineItems")])
    }
```

This is my generic panel template: it should render the data in the top divs and then simply render the body passed to it in the model:

```
<div class="${panelClass}">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            ${panelTitle}
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            ${body}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my timeline template: it should render the details of each of the timeline variables passed in the model by the controller.

```
<g:each in="${timelineItems}">
    <p>${it.details}</p>
</g:each>
```

I'm expecting to see a div which includes something like:

```
Some text in the body here
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some other text</p>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error evaluating expression [it.details] : No such property: details for class: java.lang.String
```

My map appears to be being converted to a string and I can't access the map.  What am I doing wrong please?  I want to define multiple tags which can be used inside one another.  How do I do this?

Comment: You have to use `{}` in `dash:timelinePanel` as `<dash:timelinePanel timelineItems="${timelineItems}" />`. Without this interpolation, `$timelineItems` will be treated as String.

Comment: btw, you can use `g:render template=` directly from gsp, w/o introducing a taglib

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro and Igor, that's removed the error that was causing the app to crash.  However, I now see the output as being a single string: "Some text in the body here <p>Some text that we want to have appear in the main panel</p><p>Some text that we want to have appear in the second main panel</p>"  Is there something I can do to cause the contents of the timeline template to be interpreted as a string?

Comment: Ah, it appears that I needed to put the encoding as "raw" do get it to work properly.  So, in the timelinePanel tag lib, put 'encoding: "raw"' as one of the items in the map (or make raw the default encoding for the whole tag lib class).